# Prove $e^x > 1 + x +\frac{ x^2}{2!} + ··· + \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for $x>0$ with induction.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, induction

I'm having trouble starting with the base case even. So far I've set 
$$
f_n(x)=1 + x +\frac{ x^2}{2!} + ··· + \frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$
 For $n = 0$, $e^x>f_0(x)$, but I'm not sure that's the correct base case since usually $n=1$ is used.

From there, I'm having dificulty establishing $e^x>f_{k+1}(x)$.

I can use derivation, but cannot use integration of any kind. I must use indiction. I do not have a formal definition of $e^x$, and my textbook is not useful or good.

EDIT: I cannot use the power series of $e^x,$ my apologies for taking the question incorrectly!

Comment: Let us consider $$g_n(x)=e^x-\left(1 + x +\frac{ x^2}{2!} + ··· + \frac{x^n}{n!}\right)\ .$$ We have $g_n(0)=0$. What can we say (inductively) about the monotonicity of this function, using the derivative for instance?

Comment: Given you tag this as `power-series`, does this mean you can use the power series of $e^x$?

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$?

Comment: My mistake, I cannot use the power series of $e^x$. Sorry for the confusion and I updated the question!

Comment: Which definition/properties are allowed for your problem? If one knows that $(e^x)' = e^x$, then one may argue $$ [\forall x > 0 \ : \ e^x > f_n(x)] \quad \Rightarrow \quad \forall x > 0 \ : \ e^x = 1+\int_{0}^{x}e^t \, dt > 1+\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t) \, dt = f_{n+1}(x). $$

Comment: @SangchulLee I cannot use integration of any form. I dont have much at this stage besides preliminary introduction of induction and derivatives

Comment: Set $g_n(x) = e^x - f_n(x)$ and notice that $g'_{n+1} = g_n$ and $g_n(0) = 0$. Then try to apply the mean-value theorem to $g_n(x) = g_n(x) - g_n(0)$. (This is essentially what dan_fulea suggested.)

Comment: What is the author and name of your textbook?

Comment: Without a definition of $e^x$ you can't do anything. It's like trying to decide the color of a widget without knowing what  a widget is

Answer (score 3):

If you know calculus, we can consider the [Maclaurin series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) for $e^x$:
$$ e^x = 1+x+\frac1{2!}x^2+\frac1{3!}x^3+\frac1{4!}x^4+\cdots.$$
Notice that each term in the series is positive! The function in the inequality is just this expression, but terminiating after a finite number of terms. But there are always more terms after where you terminated, and these terms are positive. Thus $e^x$ is greater than the expression you gave.

Answer (score 1):

By integration by parts
$$ e^x-f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}e^t\,dt $$
and the integral of a positive function over an interval is positive. Actually

$$ e^x-f_n(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t)^n e^{xt}\,dt = \frac{x^{n+1}e^x}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}t^n e^{-xt}\,dt$$
is greater than
$$ \frac{x^{n+1}e^x}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}t^n(1-t)^x\,dt =\frac{x^{n+1}e^x}{n!}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(n+x+2)}=\frac{x^{n+1}e^x}{(x+1)_{n+1}}.$$